# Rails: many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, associations

In my Rails application I want to count all identical fonctions(job has_many: fonctions) between a given job and other job so for this I'm doing in my job model

```
  def fonctions_score
    (Job.fonctions.collect(&:id) & self.fonctions.collect(&:id)).size
  end
```

I have already done this

```
  def fonctions_score
    Job.includes(:fonctions).where(fonctions: { id: self.fonctions.pluck(:id) } ).size
  end
```

but it returns 2 when all job fonctions are similar and 1 when none of them are similar

but this return `undefined method 'fonctions'` for error

Comment: You question is unclear, try to review and possibly rephrase what you are trying to achieve

Comment: i want to sort job similar to given job based on the number of similar fonctions so for this i want to count the number of similar fonction for each job ex: Job1.fonction= "web", "management", strategy" and Job2.fonctions ="management", "marketing" this must give me the % of 1/3 when sorting similar job to Job1. I hope i was clear

Answer (score 0):

This will return the number of duplicates functions between a given job and another passed as a parameter.

In your Job model:

```
def count_indentical_functions job_id
  JobFonction.where(id: self.id)
    .joins('INNER JOIN job_fonctions b
            ON b.job_id = #{job_id}
            AND job_fonctions.fonction_id = b.fonction_id')
      .count
end
```

So, now you can compare one job to another by calling:

```
job.count_identical_functions other_job_id
```

I tried my best. If it is not what you really want, please try to reformulate clearly your question and provide an example of the desired output.